# system("/bin/sh") closes immediately when input given through pipe

Tags: c, shell, terminal, pipe, system

I wrote a c program as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
        int a;
        scanf("%d",&a);
        system("/bin/sh");
        return 0;
}
```

compiled it and when i execute the a.out file it shows something like this:

```
user@system:~/dir$ ./a.out
123                           <- this is the input that I gave
$ whoami
user
```

so here I get a proper sub shell called through c
now if I execute the a.out file using input through pipe it shows like this:

```
user@system:~/dir$ echo 123 | ./a.out
user@system:~/dir$
```

it simply executes the command, creates the shell, terminates the shell and exits.

I am sure that it executes the sub shell because on doing `echo 123 | ltrace ./a.out` it shows like this:

```
system("/bin/sh" <no return ...>
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) ---
<... system resumed> )                                                              = 0
+++ exited (status 0) +++
```

which means there is a sub shell created 
I cant understand what difference does the two methods make

Comment: What do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sh` will read the `stdin` till it is encountering the EOF.
In the first case you do not send `EOF` (which can be done by pressing `Ctrl-D` depending on your environment). In the second case the `EOF` is happening after the piped input is exhausted (that is after the `echo 123` is done).
To understand better you can simulate the `sh` behavior with a simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char input[100];
    while(fgets(input, 100, stdin)) {
        printf("Echoing back: %s\n", input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can compile it and run with your `system()` call instead of `sh` and observe a similar behavior.

Comment: when I run `(echo 123; echo pwd) | ./a.out` it doesn't run the command in the terminal. Here after assigning 123 to the variable, "pwd" is still in the input stream. EOF is not encountered but still it doesn't print the directory. On changing the order of `system("/bin/sh")` and `scanf` in the original code it works fine.